# Reactjs autoscroll to bottom of container

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a basic chat application where the use enters a message, then it appears on the screen.  Like a normal messaging system I'd like the scroll bar to be at the bottom point by default.  I've attempted to that that with the code below.

Here is the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-pasteur-nz32o

And the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Messages extends Component {
  setScroll() {
    this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto" });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setScroll();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setScroll();
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.messages.map(message => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{message.message}</h2>
          <div
            style={{ float: "left", clear: "both" }}
            ref={el => {
              this.messagesEnd = el;
            }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

It works fine, however if there is a scrollbar in a component outside that container it also sets that to the bottom as well.  Is there any way I can only set the scroll bar of the container to bottom (independent of any other scroll bars on the screen)?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is not really clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `setScroll` to include `block: 'end'` as an option for `scrollIntoView`:

```
setScroll() {
    this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto", block: "end" });
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-water-463xy